# Где лучше хранить ключи для шифрования? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

При регистрации я шифрую данные на клиенте и ещё раз на сервере перед занесением его БД.
На сервере просто XOR, а на клиенте думаю сделать шифрованием с ключом, боюсь перехвата при запросах.

1. Можно ли шифровать с ключом, храня его прямо в коде? Есть ли смысл выносить его в .env?

2. Может ли злоумышленник изменить javascript на клиенте и вшить что-либо туда?
   Если это произойдёт, то в любом случае пиши пропало? Как защититься от этого?

Comment: https и никакого перехвата при запросах

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, а изменить код на странице при заходе пользователя невозможно? Слышал, возможно. Либо было возможно...

Comment: JS и HTML код могут меняться пользователем как угодно. И что? Какая цель такой "защиты"?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Так самим пользователем-то ладно, а речь идёт о некоем со стороны.

Comment: В https устанавливается соединение точка-точка. И третья сторона может только повредить трафик. А прочитать его или изменить не сможет